# Content not displaying on Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

None of my content is displaying when I pull up my website. The only thing that shows is the header and footer. I did not edit the page.php file so I know this can't be it. I made some changes to the css to make the header and footer full-width and suddenly everything was gone. The content is still in my page editor but does not display in the web browser. I tried deactivating all of the plugins, but that did not seem to work. Only one page displays content.

My website is [www.smaysdesigns.com](http://www.smaysdesigns.com)

Comment: Unless you can pinpoint this problem to be programming related, it does not fall within the scope of this site and you will probably not get an answer.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: The problem is I don't know what code is causing the problem. I tried increasing the pcre.backtrack_limit directive but that did not work either.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have set `.entry-title` and `.entry-content` to `visibility: hidden`

If you remove that from your css, the content shows up.

Comment: Thanks zarex360 . In my haste to remove the .entry-title I added visibility: hidden it to content as well.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate your theme, and activate again (sometimes this helps). If you have a backup place your backup.

You can get more info with WP DEBUG, enable WP DEBUG to check the error(s).

add `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` to wp-config.php
and check the error(s).

Comment: you add visibility hidden to the entry content, this hide the content. remove the line or make visibility: visible;

.entry-content, .entry-summary {
   visibility: hidden;
}

Comment: Thanks, this was pointed out to me. Don't know how I overlooked that.

Comment: @SMays can you tick it as correct answer